# how to redirect on edittext when click on icon or image?

Tags: android

Following is my xml file. I want that when I click `imgDescAddCity` it will redirect on next `EditText` which is `txtDescAddCity`. It is like a WhatsApp status when we click on edit or change status icon it can allow writing new status in `EditText` same as hear. I want that when I click on imgDescAddCity icon cursor will redirect on txtDescAddCity `EditText`.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/header_new_city"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include"
    android:background="@color/backgroundLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtCityNameAddCity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="City name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView141"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.75"
                        android:text="Description"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgDescAddCity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_border_color_black" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtDescAddCity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="description here" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.75"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:entries="@array/addcity" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView82"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/search_magnifying" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtSeasonToVisitAddCity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Best season to visit"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.75"
                        android:text="City photo" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgAttachAddCity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/attach" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewAddCityImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/lightBlue"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="city"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/backgroundColor" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: txtDescAddCity.requestFocus();

Comment: you can try your edit text object.requestFocus()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per [my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616954/how-to-redirect-on-edittext-when-click-on-icon-or-image/46616983#comment80185480_46616954)

use `requestFocus` method on `edittext`

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

try [this](https://www.android-examples.com/add-requestfocus-on-edittext-programmatically-android/) tutorial.

Comment: But i don't want directly insert data in that edit text .but when user click on icon which is imgDescAddCity at that time it can go on edit text .